# okHttp requests + retrofit share session

Tags: android, session, retrofit, okhttp

I have an old app which uses raw okhttp calls and utilizes sessions.
OkHttp is setup by this code:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = null;
    try {

        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = SupportRequests.getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
        builder.readTimeout(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        builder.connectTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
        cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
        builder.cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager));
        okHttpClient = builder.build();

        SupportRequests.setOkHttpClient(okHttpClient);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
        FirebaseCrash.report(e);
    }
```

I want to switch to using retrofit. The app is quite big and contains several dozens requests. Making it in a one-time switch is not possible.

I tried to start switching and encountered a problem.

Retrofit and okHtpp raw calls do not share PHP session.
I create retrofit with following code:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                .baseUrl(Preferences.getInstance().server)
                                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(SupportGson.get()))
                                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                                .client(okHttpClient)
                                .build();

    retrofitProvider.setRetrofit(retrofit);
```

But sessions are different for retrofit calls and raw okhttp calls.

Any idea how to make them share session?

Comment: you are using the same okHttpClient for both?

Comment: yes. the same .